# How to raise runtime error when a namelist variable is missing in an input namelist file?

Tags: fortran

An example code is as follows:

```
program main
 implicit none
 integer :: ufile
 real :: a, b, c
 namelist /my_nlt/ a, b, c
 open(newunit=ufile,file='my_nlt.txt')
 read(ufile,my_nlt)
 close(ufile)
 write(*,my_nlt)
end program main
```

And the input file `my_nlt.txt` contains:

```
 &my_nlt
 a=1.0
 b=2.0
  /
```

Here the variable `c` is missing in the input file.
Running the code compiled by `gfortran` gives no warnning/error. I am wondering whether there is a compiler option that can be used to raise an error/warning when encountering this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not aware of such an option for gfortran (or any other Fortran compiler).  I would also strongly recommend not relying on such an option should one be found.

Namelist formatting exists to give a certain simplicity and flexibility of input to specific objects.  Desiring a warning with a namelist read not updating all variables is perhaps trying to use the tool inappropriately.

For the program and input of the question, the expected runtime behaviour is for `a` and `b` to be defined with the values stated, and for `c` to be undefined.  Instead, we could define the three variables with a value prior to the read and see whether they are updated by the read:

```
real, parameter :: SENTINEL=HUGE(0.)
real :: a=SENTINEL, b=SENTINEL, c=SENTINEL
namelist /my_nlt/ a, b, c
open(newunit=ufile,file='my_nlt.txt')
read(ufile,my_nlt)

if (a==SENTINEL.or.b==SENTINEL.or.c==SENTINEL) ERROR STOP
```

Here `SENTINEL` would be a value undesired for the variables or unexpected in the input.  A variable not included in a namelist record retains its value prior to the read.

This isn't the same thing as certainly not appearing (especially where there may be no out-of-range input value) but if you want to check that then you'll have to parse the input file manually.  The structure of such a namelist file is well defined.

As a final consideration, is the variable `c` "present" in the following namelist input record?

```
&my_nlt a=1., b=2., c=1* /
```

Comment: Adding to @francescalus' excellent answer, a NAMELIST read where a variable is not named leaves the variable in its previous definition status. I'll note that you can't even rely on a compiler's uninitialized variable checking to detect this.

Comment: If the input file looks like `&my_nlt a=1.0,b=2.0, c=2+1 /`, `c` still gets a value without error (tested using gfortran), but the value is not as we expected. To just test whether a variable presents, maybe the safest way is to parse the input file manually.

Comment: @francescalus mentioned "Desiring a warning with a namelist read not updating all variables is perhaps trying to use the tool inappropriately". I do not understand this. It seems to me that warning for a missing variable is a reasonable enhancement for the robustness of fortran namelist.

Comment: @YoujunHu, my comment about using the tool "inappropriately" relates to how namelist input is designed not to affect variables which don't feature in the input record (and may appear in any order, or incompletely), which is in stark contrast to the other form of formatted input. Think of it as a facility like command line arguments: the user expects to be able to give just a selection of values on the command line, perhaps leaving others as "default values" or unspecified.

Comment: @YoujunHu, `c` has a well-defined value from the namelist record `&my_nlt a=1.0,b=2.0, c=2+1 /`.  That value is `20.`.  [If you don't understand why, then that could make a good question.]

Comment: @francescalus, The value I got is indeed `20` and I indeed do not understand why.

Comment: @YoujunHu, it's 20 because `2+1` as input field is interpreted as 2 with exponent 1 (2×10^1).